# How to get similar sound on two or more (identical) sprite click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d. In my game, different colors of balloon are spawning **randomly** from the bottom and there is a particular sound associated with similar (two or more) sprite/balloon **click** which is not working. Eg. With balloon image red.png a red.wav is associated and with blue.png, blue.wav is there and so on. Again when red balloon comes, red.wav is associated with it. Following is the code which i am using for sound association:-

- (void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation 
  {
  for (CCSprite *sprite in targets) 
  {

  ```
  if (CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], touchLocation))

  {
      //NSLog(@"sprite was touched");
      NSLog(@"strGetImgName%@",strGetImgName);
      [targets removeObject:sprite];
      if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon1"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button1.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon2"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button2.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon3"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button3.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon4"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button4.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon5"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button5.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon6"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button6.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon7"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button7.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon8"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button8.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon9"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button9.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else if ([strGetImgName isEqualToString:@"balloon10"]) {
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button10.wav"];
          [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
      }
      else {
          NSLog(@"nothing remaining");
      }

      [self balloonBlastAnimation:sprite];


      [sprite.parent removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];


      break;

  }
  ```

  }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution to my problem and it worked beautifully :)

// I have set a tag for each balloon and used switch case method. Here is the code i used.

-(void)addTarget {
    int enType= arc4random() % 11;

```
CCSprite *target=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"balloon%d.png",enType]  rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 119)];
target.tag = enType;
```

// And the switch-case method

- (void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation 
  {

  for (CCSprite *sprite in targets) 
  {

  ```
  if (CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], touchLocation))

  {
      switch (sprite.tag) {
          case 1:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button1.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
            case 2:  
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button2.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 3:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button3.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 4:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button4.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 5:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button5.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 6:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button6.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 7:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button7.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 8:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button8.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 9:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button9.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          case 10:
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button10.wav"];
              [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  ```

Comment: All i had to to do was to generate a unique sound on two or more similar balloon click. There was actually no need for creating strings and all. Simply associating balloons with tag will do.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to code for the same output. All of the above mentioned methods are equally good. Yet it is always better to find the solution by yourself...!!

Comment: this is essentially my way of doing it, as enums are just a list of values given 0 - end of list. glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an enum to do this, its less expensive and can be done with a simple switch.

Declare your enum

```
typedef enum {
    BalloonType_1,
    BalloonType_2,
    BalloonType_3
} BalloonType;
```

Subclass CCSprite - maybe BalloonSprite, give it an enum as a property

```
@interface BalloonSprite : CCSprite {

    BalloonType typeOfBalloon;

}
```

@synthesis a property, or make your own method declarations for getting and setting (I do this because when I set my object types, I set health/armour other values within the sprite)

```
-(BalloonType) typeOfBalloon;
-(void) setTypeOfBalloon:(BalloonType) type;
```

When creating your sprite, set the type of balloon it is.

Then your method for playing your wavs looks something like this..

```
switch ([sprite typeOfBalloon]) {
   case: BalloonType_1 {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button1.wav"];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
   }
        break;
   case: BalloonType_2 {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button2.wav"];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
   }
        break;
   case: BalloonType_3 {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"button3.wav"];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:4.0f];
   }
        break;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Balloon should be a class, each Balloon is an instance of the Balloon class.

When you initialize the balloon, you would then do:

```
Balloon* newBalloon1 = [[Balloon alloc] initWithFile:@"balloon-red.png" sound:@"poppedipopp.wav"];
Balloon* newBalloon2 = [[Balloon alloc] initWithFile:@"balloon-blue.png" sound:@"pluppeddi.wav"];
Balloon* newBalloon3 = [[Balloon alloc] initWithFile:@"balloon-green.png" sound:@"flupffrrrrfrrr.wav"];
```

The init method does this:

```
-(id) initWithFile:(NSString*)imageFile sound:(NSString*)sound
{
  if ((self = [super init]))
  {
     sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:imageFile];
     soundFile = sound;
  }
}
```

The @interface declares CCSprite* sprite and NSString* soundFile as instance variables.

When the balloon is supposed to pop, you'll send the pop message to the balloon:

```
[aBalloon pop];
```

The pop method is implemented as follows:

```
-(void) pop
{
   // maybe play an animation

   [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:soundFile];
}
```

Thus balloons become self-contained objects that know what they are supposed to do, and a balloon can be parameterized during initialization or possibly via properties.

Bongeh's suggestion for actually creating the balloons based on their type still applies.